# If field is nothing, disable "Go to report" action - not working?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a "Detail" button in my report that should only show if there is data in the Start and End columns of that row.

Right now, my setup for my Detail text box is:

General > Expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!StartTime.Value) OR IsNothing(Fields!EndTime.Value), nothing, "Detail")
```

Action > Go to report > Specify a report > Expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!StartDate.Value) OR IsNothing(Parameters!EndDate.Value), Nothing, "Detail Report")
```

In the report viewer via browser, once you run the report, the cells where `Nothing` should be applied show a hyphen (-). This hyphen can be clicked on for some reason, despite my "Specify a report" code. However, in the PDF version (or other exported) version of the report, the hyphen is not there. I don't care that the hyphen is there (and I also don't know *why* it's there), but it can't be clicked on.

If I run the report in Visual Studio I don't see the hyphen. It's when I upload it to our report server and access it from chrome. Once this hyphen is clicked on, it gives an error saying "The 'StartDate' parameter is missing a value."

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a mistake on my part. In my goto action, I was referencing `Parameters!StartDate.Value` and `Parameters!EndDate.Value`, while in my "Detail" text box expression I had it referencing `Fields!StartTime.Value` and `Fields!EndTime.Value`. I changed the goto action to the latter, and my problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nothing as the report name, set the report to 0.

So set the goto action as this :

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!StartDate.Value) OR IsNothing(Parameters!EndDate.Value), 0, "Asset Drilldown Report")
```

Comment: Hey Harry, thanks for the suggestion. Gave this a shot and unfortunately am seeing the same behavior, the hyphen still appears. If I run the report in Visual Studio I don't see the hyphen. It's when I upload it to our report server and access it from chrome. I forgot to mention that once this hyphen is clicked on, it gives an error saying "The 'StartDate' parameter is missing a value."

Comment: Do the StartDate and EndDate parameters allow for nulls? I can only hazard a guess that the isnothing of either of the parameter values is not evaluating to well.. nothing. can you place the expression in a text box and see what it resolves to? let it show a value of 0 or 1 so then you can know for certain what it is doing?

Comment: Found out what was wrong... a mistake on my part. I had my goto action pointing to `Parameters!StartDate.Value` and `Parameters!EndDate.Value`, they should have been pointing to `Fields!StartTime.Value` and `Fields!EndTime.Value`. It works now. Thanks Harry.